# How to generate unique Auto increament id field across multiple data centers?

Tags: mysql

I have multiple mysql servers deployed in three different data centers. Now my database has few tables with Auto increment id column. I want these columns in all three data center must have unique id across the data centers. Is it possible in Mysql or i need to generate these columns programmatically ?

For example in data center D1 has table T1 with id 1, then data centers D2 and D3 must not generate id 1 for table T1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset settings.  Each server will have a different offset value, and they will all increment enough each time to "hop over" and leave room for the numbers your other servers will generate.  There's some good docs about it here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html

Comment: Is it possible to append or prefix a fix number to generated number ?

Comment: Not as far as I know.  It's just going to pick a new number each time based on the increment and offset settings.  You might consider a second column with a server id for instance, and make both columns your key.  That will mean some app side involvement though.

Comment: Another direction you can take is to use UUIDs as your key instead of an auto-increment integer.  UUIDs would be guaranteed to be unique regardless of how many servers you had.  MySQL has a handy UUID() function built in and ready to go for that.

Comment: Ok. But UUID are difficult to read as an entity's identifiers.We are generally used to say "I am talking about entity id 234 or 123" etc. Yes its also a considerable option !